# How to execute an ansible ad-hoc command only once when there are several hosts under the same category

Tags: ansible

I would like to run a certain ansible ad-hoc command only on one host from a group of hosts. Say in the hosts file I have a few hosts under group name [webserver], I want to be able to run the command only on one of the hosts in that group, no matter which.
I wasn't able to find an answer for that in ansible ad-hoc doc

Comment: [Introduction To Ad-Hoc Commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Say I have under hosts file

```
[webserver]
wserver-1
wserver-2
wserver-3
```

And I want to choose the webserver that comes first (doesn't matter which)
and run some command on it.

The way to do that is as follows:

```
ansible -i /etc/ansible/hosts webserver[0] -m shell -a 'hostname'
```

This will run 'hostname' on wserver-1

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the list of inventory  as comma separated values or gorup in command line with ad-hoc command .

```
ansible-playbook -i emample-host.com, -a <ad hoc command>
```

Refer [Introduction to Ad hoc command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html)